# C++ template class gives syntax errors without apparent errors

Tags: c++, templates, syntax-error, doubly-linked-list

I have written a "Node" template class for a doubly linked list.

Header file:

```
template< class T >
class Node
{
public:
    Node();
    ~Node();

    Node<T>* GetNext();
    Node<T>* GetPrev();

    void SetNext( Node<T>* pNode );
    void SetPrev( Node<T>* pNode );

    void SetData( T& data );
    T*  GetData();

private:
    Node<T>*    p_Next;
    Node<T>*    p_Prev;
    T*      p_Data; 
};



template< class T >
Node<T>::Node() : p_Next(NULL), p_Prev(NULL), p_Data(NULL)
{

}

//======================================================================================

template< class T >
Node<T>::~Node()
{
    if( p_Data != NULL)
        delete p_Data;

    p_Next = NULL;
    p_Prev = NULL;
}

//======================================================================================

template< class T >
Node<T>* Node<T>::GetNext()
{
    return p_Next;
}

//======================================================================================

template< class T >
Node<T>* Node<T>::GetPrev()
{
    return p_Prev;
}

//======================================================================================

template< class T >
void Node<T>::SetData( T& data )
{
    if(p_Data == NULL)
        p_Data = new T;

    *p_Data = data;
}

//======================================================================================

template< class T >
T*  Node<T>::GetData()
{
    return p_Data;
}
```

When I try to compile it Visual Studio gives me the following syntax errors in the line that has the constructor implementation.

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
error C2059: syntax error : '<'
error C2588: '::~Node' : illegal global destructor
fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

I cannot identify any syntax errors as mentioned above. Please help me, what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compiles fine on VS2010.

Comment: Is this the entire header? I bet there must be some additional code, such as header guards or include directives. The code you gave compile perfectly (after including `<cstddef>` or another header defining `NULL`), so the problem must be in some code that you have not posted. My bet would be that you forgot a semi-colon after a class definition that is included before `Node`, but this is a wild guess.

Comment: Also, you should use `const T&` instead of `T&` in `SetData()`.

Comment: Compiles fine on Qt Creator too.

Comment: I used VS2008. It does compile fine in 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't included some definition for NULL.

Please consider to using `nullptr` instead. In VS2010 you might need to add a definition for that, but when changing to a fully C++11 compatible compiler, you will be using the C++ keyword that has been designed for that purpose.